# Identify Error with ArcGIS Server 9.3

Tags: arcgis-server

I am receiving an error ("Error executing identify") when I try to perform an identify operation on map running on ArcGIS Server 9.3.  All of the inputs appear to be correct when I check them in the ArcGIS Server Directory.

The map I am using has over 90 layers.  Could that possibly be causing an issue with the identify operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

It sounds like your "Error executing identify" is probably a non-specific timeout message.  It isn't just the number of layers, but the complexity of those layers as well.  If you really need to identify on all of those layers, you may want to try writing a task instead that can take the input and work in the background and return the result to the user when it is done.

You could also try combining datasets together to create fewer featureclasses to identify.  They could be identify-only services while the others are for visualization.

---

Previous response:

What framework are you using for the identify?  Is this in ArcMap, WebADF, REST/javascript/Flex/Silverlight?  If it is browser-based, have you used Firebug or Fiddler (or equivalent) to see what the request and response messages show?

If you are trying to identify and return results on all 90+ layers, that could be the issue.  It could be a time-out.  The server response message should give you a good idea of the problem.

Comment: The framework is Silverlight and I have used Fiddler to get the exact request.

When I have the layers set to "all", I get the "Error executing identify" message.  However, if I specify just one layer, the identify operation works correctly.

The server has not given any indication of a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall there being an identify "all" option available in Silverlight. If I remember correctly, you'll need to perform an identify on each layer programmatically if you want to identify features on more than one layer.

From a server standpoint [and, potentially, an end-user standpoint] it's better to do that any way. What are the odds that the user *really* wants to identify features on 90 different layers and view all the results at the same time? If it makes sense for your app to identify several layers at a time, provide a "group identification" function to the user, then programmatically identify the features from those layers and present them to the user.

Comment: The LayerOption enum in the ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks namespace allows choices of "Top", "Visible", and "All".  That LayerOption is then included in the IdentifyParameters object which are used for the Identify operation.

Comment: Good to know. I still stand by my opinion that using "All" may not be in your (or your user's) best interest.